# Set GOP length for HEVC-Encoding in ffmpeg

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, hevc

I want to encode an xxx.y4m file to hevc and set the GOP-length to a particular value, open and closed gop.

To encode I'm using :

```
...>ffmpeg -i xxx.y4m -c copy xxx.hevc
```

this gives me the hevc-encoded file, now I want to set a particular gop-length

```
...>ffmpeg -i xxx.y4m -c:v libx265 -keyint=1 -open-gop=1 -c copy xxx.hevc
```

is not working because "option not found"

kind regards

Answer (score 5):

This command,

```
ffmpeg -i xxx.y4m -c copy xxx.hevc
```

does not perform any encoding. It simply streamcopys the raw video stream.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i xxx.y4m -c:v libx265 -x265-params keyint=100:no-open-gop xxx.hevc
```

`keyint` sets the GOP size. GOPs are open by default, and you can use the option above for closed GOPs.

Whenever `-c copy` is set, there is no encoding occurring.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why I wrote "-c copy". I did the "-x265-params" wrong.